# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'

Tags: c#, wpf

I create a Note-Taking application using C# and WPF. I have problem with binding property of UserControl "Checked" and "UnChecked". I haven't any idea why error occurs. Error occures in the constructor of class "Task". All properties initializes right, error occures exactly in the constructor

**This is my xaml:**

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="ToDoList.Task"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ToDoList"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="170" d:DesignWidth="500"
             Name="TaskControl"
             Height="170" MinWidth="300">
    <Border CornerRadius="30" Background="#bbb" Opacity="0.8">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RadioButton Unchecked="{Binding UnChecked, ElementName=TaskControl}" Checked="{Binding Checked, ElementName=TaskControl}" FontFamily="Calibri" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Style="{DynamicResource TaskString}" Content="{Binding TaskStr, ElementName=TaskControl}" FontSize="50" Margin="5"></RadioButton>
            <Label Content="{Binding Deadline, ElementName=TaskControl}" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Calibri" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Label>
            <TextBox FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Thin" BorderThickness="0" Background="#bbb" Text="{Binding Description, ElementName=TaskControl}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Calibri"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

**This is my C# code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ToDoList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Task.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class Task : UserControl
    {
        private static void BaseFunc(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Declare properties
        public string TaskStr
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TaskProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TaskProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Task.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TaskProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("TaskStr", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Test"));

        

        public string Description
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Description.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("Test"));



        public string Deadline
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DeadlineProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DeadlineProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Deadline.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DeadlineProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Deadline", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("07/02/2007"));

        // Base function for events "Checked" and "UnChecked"
        static RoutedEventHandler r = BaseFunc;

        public RoutedEventHandler Checked
        {
            get { return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(CheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Checked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Checked", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(r));



        public RoutedEventHandler UnChecked
        {
            get { return (RoutedEventHandler)GetValue(UnCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UnCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UnChecked.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UnChecked", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(r));



        public Task()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: At least the third parameter of `DependencyProperty.Register` should be `typeof(Task)`. I don't think this naming is good because it may conflict with `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` though.

Comment: Custom events must be registered using [EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.eventmanager.registerroutedevent), not `DependencyProperty.Register`. See e.g. http://wpftutorial.net/RoutedEvents.html for an example